# Facebook SDK - subscriptions with trial period and discount period

Tags: facebook, analytics, subscription

We are trying now to add Facebook SDK to our android and ios applications and using received data to optimize facebook advertisment.
But now it's not clear for me how facebook analytics take account of trial, discount and renewal subscriptions.
I made some tests and it seems for me that all this subscription types just summarized like general subscriptions.
But this is not what out marketing team want see in facebook analytics.
Is it important for them see trial subscription as 0 on the profit chart at trial period and as full price after trial period.
And same situation for discount subscriptions.
Are my assumptions correct?
Or do I have to send subscriptions purchase events some other way to get necessary results?